# How can I filter rows which contains 2 or more words from another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to filter rows that contain 2 or more words located in another column.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    df <- data.frame(name1 = c("Carlos Lopez Rey", "Monica Naranjo Garcia", "Antonio Perez Reverte", "Alejandro Martinez Amor", "Iñigo Muruzabal"), 
                     name2 = c("Lopez, Carlos", "Monica de Naranjo", "Garcia, Antonio", "Alejandro Martinez de Amor", "Muruzabal, Javier"))
```

And I would like to create a condition that filters rows that contain 2 or more same words in the first column (name1) and in the second column (name2). The result I would like to have is:

| name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- |
| Carlos Lopez Rey | Lopez, Carlos |
| Monica Naranjo Garcia | Monica de Naranjo |
| Alejandro Martinez Amor | Alejandro Martinez de Amor |

* Notice that "Antonio Perez Reverte" and " Iñigo Muruzabal" are not filtered because the first column only matches 1 word with the second column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string on words, find common words using `length(intersect(...))` and select only rows that have at least 2 words in common.

```
result <- subset(df, mapply(function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)), 
                     strsplit(name1, ',|\\s+'), strsplit(name2, ',|\\s+')) >= 2)

result

#                    name1                      name2
#1        Carlos Lopez Rey              Lopez, Carlos
#2   Monica Naranjo Garcia          Monica de Naranjo
#4 Alejandro Martinez Amor Alejandro Martinez de Amor
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! 
and how could I do the same process but with different dataframes? I mean that I have the same columns but in different dataframes but with different lengths (first df has 342 rows and the second dataframe has 1557 rows)
I would like to get the rows that have 2 or more same words in comparison with the other column from the other dataframe. (I have tried your solution indicating explicitly the df and the column and it does'nt work because of the different lengths of the df) 

Thanks again!

Comment: If the dataframes have different lengths this answer would require some change. You may ask that as a new question so that it is easier to help.

Comment: just posted it! here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116895/how-can-i-filter-a-dataframe-which-has-similar-data-from-another-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Thanks to Martin Gal's valuable suggestion:

Please consider to merge the two`mutate` and the `filter` into one line:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
filter(str_detect(name2, str_replace_all(name1," ", "|")))
```

**1. Answer:**
We could create a pattern column with `str_replace_all` and then flag with `str_detect` and then `filter` all rows where string from `name1` is in `name2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(pattern_name1 = str_replace_all(name1," ", "|")) %>% 
  mutate(flag = str_detect(name2, pattern_name1)) %>% 
  filter(flag == TRUE) %>% 
  select(1,2)
```

output:

```
             name1                      name2
1        Carlos Lopez Rey              Lopez, Carlos
2   Monica Naranjo Garcia          Monica de Naranjo
3   Antonio Perez Reverte            Garcia, Antonio
4 Alejandro Martinez Amor Alejandro Martinez de Amor
5         Iñigo Muruzabal          Muruzabal, Javier
```

Comment: (1) Shouldn't it be `filter(flag == TRUE)`? (2) You could merge the two `mutate` and the `filter` into one line: `filter(str_detect(name2, str_replace_all(name1," ", "|")))` and even spare the `select()`

Comment: Thanks Martin Gal. Will change as soon as i am on a desktop pc. Now mobile

Comment: It's only a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve with a `for-loop`

Your dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("Carlos Lopez Rey", "Monica Naranjo Garcia", "Antonio Perez Reverte", "Alejandro Martinez Amor", "Iñigo Muruzabal"), 
                 name2 = c("Lopez, Carlos", "Monica de Naranjo", "Garcia, Antonio", "Alejandro Martinez de Amor", "Muruzabal, Javier"))
```

Remove commas and split in spaces:

```
name1 <- strsplit(gsub(",","",df$name1),  ' ')
name2 <- strsplit(gsub(",","",df$name2), ' ')
```

Now use the loop to find the rows:

```
rows <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    # i = 1
    if (sum(name1[[i]] %in% name2[[i]]) > 1){
        rows <- append(rows, i)
    }
}

df_select <- df[rows,]
```