# How can I filter a dataframe which has similar data from another dataframe?

Tags: r

I would like to filter a dataframe in which I have a column with different names. The filter I need to apply has to filter that dataframe by the names which are similar (2 or more words in common) with another column with different names from another dataframe. The problem is that the length of both dataframes is different: the first dataframe has 342 rows and the second dataframe has 1557 rows.

Imagine that I have this 2 dataframes:

```
  df1 <- data.frame(name1 = c("Carlos Lopez Rey", "Monica Naranjo Garcia", "Antonio Perez Reverte", "Alejandro Martinez Amor", "Iñigo Muruzabal", "Daniel Huarte", "Javier Langarica", "Yearai Bacaicoa")

  df2 <- data.frame(name2 = c("Lopez, Carlos", "Monica de Naranjo", "Garcia, Antonio", "Alejandro Martinez de Amor", "Muruzabal, Javier", "Pepe Gallego Lopez", "Fernando Alonso", "Arturo Goikoetxea", "Iñigo Lizarraga", "Laura Ripagaina", " Monica de Naranjo", "Rey Lopez, Carlos"),
                    phone = c("632548795", "658749521", "669874521", "686056350", "619106219", "687884760", "639362459", "645879521", "645214587", "613456789", "698547132", "698547123" ))
```

And I would like to get the "phone" and the "name2" for those people who have similar names (2 or more words in common) with the column "name2" from the df2.

The result I would like to get would be:

| name1 | name2 | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carlos Lopez Rey | Lopez, Carlos | 632548795 |
| Monica Naranjo Garcia | Monica de Naranjo | 658749521 |
| Alejandro Martinez Amor | Alejandro Martinez de Amor | 686056350 |
| Monica Naranjo Garcia | Monica de Naranjo | 698547132 |
| Carlos Lopez Rey | Rey Lopez, Carlos | 698547123 |

IMPORTANT: As you can see, the same name can appear multiple times in the second dataframe because an user can have multiple phone numbers assigned. I need to get every phone number assigned to every user whose name is similar to the name contained in the first dataframe.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may split the string on comma or whitespace and count the number of overlap for each combination. You can try this answer -

```
#Split string on comma or whitespace
tmp1 <- strsplit(df1$name1, ',|\\s+')
tmp2 <- strsplit(df2$name2, ',|\\s+')

#Get the corresponding matches
result <- purrr::map_df(seq_along(tmp1), function(x) {
  inds <- which(sapply(tmp2, function(y) length(intersect(tmp1[[x]], y))) >= 2)
  if(length(inds))
    dplyr::bind_cols(df1[x, , drop = FALSE], df2[inds, ])
})

result
#.                   name1                      name2     phone
#1        Carlos Lopez Rey              Lopez, Carlos 632548795
#2        Carlos Lopez Rey          Rey Lopez, Carlos 698547123
#3   Monica Naranjo Garcia          Monica de Naranjo 658749521
#4   Monica Naranjo Garcia          Monica de Naranjo 698547132
#5 Alejandro Martinez Amor Alejandro Martinez de Amor 686056350
```

Comment: instead of cbind, how could work an inner_join? Because sometimes the same name can appear multiple times in the second dataframe and with different phone numbers (different phone numbers can be assigned to the same person) 

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you update your post with an example ?

Comment: Yes! I've just updated the post with the result I would like to get (see that there are some users whose name is repeated because they have more than one phone number assigned) 

Thank you!